# Pass parameter from 1 page to another using post method

Tags: asp.net

I have a page "Demo.aspx". I need to set some parameters using post method and redirect the page to "DemoTest.aspx".

Is there any way to set parameters in post method in asp.net? I don't want to set "Querystring" due to security propose.

Also I need server side code for this. I am not able to use "Javascript" or "Jquery" for the same.
Here is some more description for the same.

Right now I am using Response.Redirect("www.ABC.Com/DemoTest.aspx?P1=2"). So the page is simply redirect to the given URL.

Now I don't want to pass that "P1" in  "Querystring". Instead of query string I want to use Post method.

Please note that redirection page is not in my own application. So I cant maintain session or "Viewstate".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `session` variable and `response.redirect` to the next page.

```
Session["MyVariable"] = "someThing";

Response.Redirect("DemoTest.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I dont want to use session or view state or Database for this. I want to use only post method.

Comment: I have to ask, why would you want to do that?

Comment: The data are secure. So I need to use Post method.

Comment: And how is that more secure than using the session where things are (usually) stored in Memory? Regardless, it is not possible to POST something to page, redirect and have those POSTed values unless they are stored somewhere, like the session.

Comment: I have to pass parameters from 1 application to another. So how could I manage that session data in another application?

Comment: Perhaps then you need to clarify on the architecture in your question. I would also add what you are trying to achieve, and not how you think it should be done and perhaps others can then suggest some options.

Comment: Now you can see my post again.

Comment: Okay. The problem with the remote system is always going to be storage of the sensitive information in relation to your session. If your own code POSTS to the remote application, it will be under a different context that the actual user's session and therefore standard sessions mechanisms will not work. Therefore, you are going to have to at least pass some kind of identifier between then systems.

Comment: You could in theory POST the information to the remote application, have it return some kind of token and then redirect the original session using this token. Unfortunately, this means passing the token in the querystring when doing a response.redirect

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in Session variables will be accessible across application.
you can store in session like this :

```
Session["id"] = "anyID";
```

To get values On another page you need to write

```
string id = Convert.ToString(Session["Id"]);
```

However
By default, in .NET pages post() do the things automatically.
You will need to do sumthing like this:

```
Server.Transfer("DemoTest.aspx", True)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I dont want to use session or view state or Database for this. I want to use only post method.